# Can gnu-screen periodically toggle between two virtual terminals?

Tags: gnu-screen

I need a way to display two multiple running processes periodically on a system console so that I don't need to manually type commands to switch between the virtual terminals running them.

So for example, I can switch between my long running process and `top` every 10 seconds to watch both at the same time.

I thought `gnu-screen` would be ideal for this but can't find a way to automatically and periodically switch between two virtual terminals. Is there a command line switch that allows for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting your `screen` session, run this (in another terminal):

```
while sleep 10s ; do screen -X next ; done
```

The `-X` option sends commands to an existing screen session, and `next` simply advances to the next window.  So if your session only has the two windows, then this will switch from one to the other.